# How to open a project in Visual Studio 2019 using command line?

Tags: command-prompt, projects-and-solutions, visual-studio-2019

I can open Angular or NativeScript or NodeJS projects in VisualStudio code by going to their directory and just type `code .` in the command line. So I am interested to know is there another command like `code .` to opening the project inside the `VisualStudio 2019` instead of `Visual Studio code`?

Comment: https://davemateer.com/2018/11/14/Open-visual-studio-from-command-line - Might be interesting

Answer (score 7):

From the command line, in the directory with your solution file, try

`start NameOfSolutionFile.sln`

Other ideas: https://davemateer.com/2018/11/14/Open-visual-studio-from-command-line

Comment: I was not aware of this, and now it's going to save me some time! Thank you!